# Doubt about semigroups in this article (anyone can help).

Tags: arithmetic, semigroups

I need help in this [article](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416). My doubt is very arithmetical and I think follows directly from the definitions. So I think anyone could help me.

The author defines what is a semigroup, gaps and non-gaps:

[image]

After that he defines what is a symmetric semigroup:

[image]

So that's my doubt:

[image]

However what I found directly from above was:

Since $H$ is not symmetric we have $\#(nL)\le nl_g-n+1\lt n(2g-1)-n+1$ which is different from the inequality the author found: $\#(nL)\lt (2n-1)(g-1)$.

I'm sure I'm forgetting some silly thing.

I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this related to arithmetic? I see more abstract algebra here.

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue the prove is essentially arithmetic. It's just sums and simple inequalities of natural numbers.